# Convert point cloud video to .las format

Tags: ros, video, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have point cloud video and I want to convert it to .las format. Maybe there is tool for point cloud video conversion to .las 3D format? Or maybe you can give an approach for achieving that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263437/convert-point-cloud-video-to-.las-format/) by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-08**:
How is this ROS related?

**Comment by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on 2017-06-09**:
Sorry, I just have a point cloud in RVIZ. I want to export it to LAS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any converts ROS point clouds to the las format. Assuming you're talking about the ASPRS LAS format? https://www.asprs.org/committee-general/laser-las-file-format-exchange-activities.html

You probably want to look into PCL methods or integrations with LAS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1